# images won't stretch to full height of parent in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex parent container .stills that has multiple image wrappers. The code works great in desktop view but not in mobile. All I want is the images to stretch to the full height of it's parent i.e full height of the screen. I want the width of the parent to automatically adjust itself to show all the images proportionally so the container has an overflow:scroll property. Then essentially you could just scroll through the container (.stills) to see all the images. I have two images inside each wrapper that interchange when the front image is clicked on so it's positioned absolute under front image. The image attached shows the still wrapper stretched to full height of the device but the images still remain small even when I set the stills container to overflow.
[image]

HTML

```
<div id="stills-ba" data-tab-content>
            <div class="stills-ba">
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/01.jpg" alt="still front">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/02.jpg" alt="still back">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/03.jpg" alt="still FRONT">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/04.jpg" alt="still back">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/05.jpg" alt="still front">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/06.jpg" alt="still 1">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/07.jpg" alt="still 4">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/08.jpg" alt="still 1">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/09.jpg" alt="still 5">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/10.jpg" alt="still 1">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/11.jpg" alt="still front">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/12.jpg" alt="still back">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

CSS

```
    #stills-ba {
        
           width: 100%;
           height:100vh;
           overflow: scroll;
        
        }
        
        .stills-ba {
           width: auto;
           height: 100vh;
           display: flex;
           overflow-y: hidden;
           -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
           -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; 
        }
        
        .still-wrapper-ba {
         width: 100%;
       height: 100vh!important; 
       left: 0;
        position: relative;
       
        
        .front-img {
        
           all: revert;
           height: auto;
           width: 100%;
           transition: opacity ease 250ms;
        }
        
        .back-img {
           all: revert;
           height: auto;
           width: 100%;
           opacity: 1;
           z-index: -5;
           position: absolute;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
        }
        
        .front-img:hover {
           opacity: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:flex;` to the **.still-wrapper-ba**, and its children (img) will get the height of **.still-wrapper-ba**.

```css
#stills-ba {

   width: 100%;
   height:100vh;
   overflow: scroll;

}

.stills-ba {
   display: flex;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; 
}

.still-wrapper-ba {
   height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow:1;

}
.front-img {
  background: yellow;
   all: revert;
   height: auto;
   width: 100vw;
   transition: opacity ease 250ms;
}

.back-img {
   all: revert;
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: -5;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.front-img:hover {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stills-ba" data-tab-content>
            <div class="stills-ba">
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/01.jpg" alt="still front">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/02.jpg" alt="still back">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/03.jpg" alt="still FRONT">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/04.jpg" alt="still back">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/05.jpg" alt="still front">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/06.jpg" alt="still 1">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/07.jpg" alt="still 4">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/08.jpg" alt="still 1">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/09.jpg" alt="still 5">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/10.jpg" alt="still 1">
               </div>
               <div class="still-wrapper-ba">
                  <img class="front-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/11.jpg" alt="still front">
                  <img class="back-img" loading="lazy" src="/img/BA/stills/12.jpg" alt="still back">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i just did this and it worked but the images are not proportionate and try to squeeze into 100vw, any idea how to make them wide

Comment: I added 100vw to img also